# Install postgres 9.0 in debian lenny

Tags: postgresql, debian

Dear all, 
 
My system has the following distribution details

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 (lenny)
Release:    5.0
Codename:   lenny
```

I need to install postgres 9.0 in this machine , but I cannot find any stable lenny packages for postgres 9.0 , Is there any other way to do this 
Any suggestion would be appreciated !

Comment: http://lists.debian.org/debian-backports-announce/2010/10/msg00000.html

Comment: This should probably be moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to the [new debian backports suite](http://lists.debian.org/debian-backports-announce/2010/10/msg00000.html), here's how to install PostgreSQL 9.0 on Debian lenny:

Add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports   main
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports-sloppy main
```

Then run these 2 commands

```
apt-get install -t lenny-backports postgresql-common
apt-get install -t lenny-backports-sloppy postgresql-9.0 postgresql-client-9.0 postgresql-contrib-9.0
```

Note that this utilizes the new lenny-backports-sloppy backport suite - please [read the announcement](http://lists.debian.org/debian-backports-announce/2010/10/msg00000.html) in order to be aware of the trade offs of using this suite.

Comment: I tried this but got error below. So this does not work ´You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libc6-i386: Depends: libc6 (= 2.3.6.ds1-13etch10) but 2.3.6.ds1-13etch5 is to be installed
  postgresql-common: Depends: postgresql-client-common (>= 111~bpo50+1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ssl-cert (>= 1.0.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`

Answer (score 1):

Installing from source is quite easy:

```
   Basically: Download postgresql-9.0.1.tar.bz2

    tar xjf postgresql-9.0.1.tar.bz2
    cd postgresql-9.0.1
    ./configure
    make 
    make install
```

Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/installation.html)

Comment: But is says dpkg error , some thing went wrong , when I discussed with my coleague , he says that we cannot install postgres  9.0 in debian lenny, is this true ?

Comment: abubacker: Debian "Lenny" (version 5) was released before Postgres 9.x and thus doesn't include packages for that major release in its update stream.  You could build and install Postgres from the sources, as described here, or you could add 3rd party entires to your sources.list (as described by Tom Feiner).  Either approach will get you access to Postgres 9 but whether you can do these things may be a matter of (your organization's) policy rather than technical feasibility.  You could also consider Debian "Squeeze" (version 6) which does include P'gres 9.0 support.

Answer (score 1):

thanks leonbloy the backport for lenny is no longer supported. use this site to download

http://ftp.riken.go.jp/pub/FreeBSD/distfiles/postgresql/

wget http://ftp.riken.go.jp/pub/FreeBSD/distfiles/postgresql/postgresql-version.tar.bz2

Then follow leonbloy's instructions above and read the file INSTALL when you uncompress the file.